# Firebase Auth When to go for Custom Authentication

Tags: firebase, jwt, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

We decided to use Firebase as our Auth Server, my requirements are very simple, in my existing Auth Table i have a column for scopes, like diff users have diff scopes, Admin, Users, Drivers etc,

1) **How can i achieve this with Firebase Auth**  (as they don't allow anything else to store in the user table)

2) **In my server i have diff modules,(urls) /admin/*   /users/* etc, i want to restrict users to their module only, with custom token i will set scope in my generated token itself, which makes its easy and i don't do any additional DB query**

3) **Can i add extra claim in Firebase Auth Token without custom Auth, as just for this i don't want to go for custom Auth.**

4) **I have two different apps one for Admin one for Users, can i have a single server in nodejs (using firebase sdk) to verify their identities with respect to their Firebase Conf JSON.**

Also i would like to know that is it a good practice to add scope in the token itself, if not what will be the recommended way .

Answer (score 1):

For now, extra claims in Firebase Auth token are only supported via custom auth. What are the main reasons that you do not want to use custom auth?

Comment: Actually my main reason for opting Firebase Auth was to avoid having an IAM server on my end.

Comment: Makes sense. What would be your preferred way to let Firebase Auth server know the claims for each user?

Answer (score 0):

I have done an app similar to the idea you are asking about, so here is what i have done

1- i added a child to the user in database and call it user type, then the type can be: Admin, Users, Drivers etc

2- you have one of 2 options;

fetch user type from database while using the app to decide what the user can and can not do or what the admin can and can not do. 
OR you do a harder work and create deferent view's and at login your app will fetch the user type once and then direct them to the view hierarchy they belong to, as you can see i followed the second option
 [image: as you can see i followed the second option]

3- i don't fully understand what you mean.

4- yes you can, after you add one app, you will have an option of adding more apps i have 2 apps and still have the option to add more[image: i have 2 apps and still have the option to add more]